# Android-Fragments and Array

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I would like to know how could I implement an array that is public to multiple fragments. I'll be using the array to store values generated from the individual fragment when a button is clicked in the respective fragments. Should I implement this in Main Activity or as a separate fragment? Kindly assist.

Comment: You can implement it in parent activity i.e. fragment activity so that it will be accessible to all fragments.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a global singleton class(Application class) to store your array. That way, you can access it through out your application.

  Its simple to create an application class. Try this easy [tutorial](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/). Once you implement it, you can access the array that is declared in your application class like so:

  ```
  ApplicationClass application = ((ApplicationClass ) getApplicationContext());  
  localArray = application .getArray();
  ```